# Android Java : Linear Layout vanishes when placed on another Linear Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am working on the `horizontal view` for a basic `Android` calculator, and I have a `LinearLayout` called `linearLayout2` that I am trying to place on top of `linearLayout3`, which contains the numbers `1, 2, 3, +, -, and (`. The problem is that when I try to move `linearLayout2` on top of `linearLayout3`, it immedietly vanishes to the top with 0 height.

Here is the `XML` code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:hint="@string/hint"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:background="#00000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button37"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button39"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button40"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button46"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button47"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="("
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button49"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button41"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button42"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button43"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="*"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button35"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="/"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button36"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text=")"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button38"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button44"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button45"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button48"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="+/-"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="%"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button51"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="^"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button52"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >

        <Button
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".16667"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="."
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3333"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button53"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="="
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/button55"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:text="Mode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:background="#ffff5830"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I assume that by `move on top layout XX` means in your case move `above layout XX`, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `Gridlayout` instead of `LinearLayout` if you want to develop a calculator.

Comment: Not sure why this was -1'd when it's a brilliant answer and gives a proper way of solving the problem. Yes, might not fix the problem in the question, but it gives the proper and actual way of doing what the asker wants.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Layout2` is using `wrap_content` for height

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

</LinearLayout>
```

but there is no content in that group (no child views) so this is correct behaviour as there is no need to make group height bigger.

Also, if you want to stack Layout2 on Layout3 you may consider wrapping themtogether in `FrameLayout` (or another `RelativeLayout`)